# What is currently the biggest prime number with no smaller undiscovered prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

Just out of curiosity, what is currently the biggest discovered prime number with no smaller undiscovered prime number?

Comment: This question, albeit interesting, is probably too localized in time for this site, since the search goes on and on and new primes in this list are probably discovered very often.

Comment: This information is most probably unpublished. Finding a prime and all those that precede it require sieve techniques, which do not allow to find very big ones. I don't think there is any competition around the "largest sieve", as this is less spectacular.

Comment: Yes, I understand this is localized in time, even though given the exponential difficulty of finding primes do give a relative time window where a response true today would hold. As for sieve techniques, you are right Yves, even though I was more interested in knowing in a "state of the art" way the lower boundary under which nobody searches for prime anymore since all have been found. Thanks for the replies anyway guys. :)